# MySQL Syntax: WHERE and LIKE clause in one query

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT bahisisim,ID FROM bahis WHERE bahisisim LIKE '%$isim%' and onay!=='0'
```

this is not working, how can i modify this?

Comment: `!==` is not a valid MySQL operator.  `<>` is SQL's not equal, though MySQL also respects `!=`.

Comment: Apart from Micheal good point, avoid '%' infront of a LIKE clause. You are going to get a table lock down the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know the use of !== operator in MySQL, try to do this:

```
SELECT bahisisim,ID FROM bahis WHERE bahisisim LIKE '%$isim%' and onay <> '0'
```

If you got a error, show to us the error for we find the solution. ;)

Answer (score 2):

there is just an error because of !==, so please change your query to :

```
SELECT bahisisim,ID FROM bahis WHERE bahisisim LIKE '%$isim%' and onay!='0';
```

OR

```
SELECT bahisisim,ID FROM bahis WHERE bahisisim LIKE '%$isim%' and onay <>'0';
```

for more you can go for http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html